# Error with wordpress theme (avada) pre-log in and on chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, wordpress-theming

My website ([enablie.co.uk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2yaO.jpg)) is not displaying properly when logged out(BuddyPress plugin).

Multiple parts of the site are broken in terms of font, layout, buttons and header logo display (logo appears two or three times depending on what brower or device being used).

Here is what site looks like in Safari logged in versus logged out (zoomed out to avoid too many pages):
[image: logged in view 1]
[image: logged in view 2]
[image: logged out view 1]
[image: logged out view 2]

The issues are worse in Chrome (e.g. icons don't load and social login (AccessPress Social Login Lite plugin) does not display when select login or register).
[image: Chrome view]

I had thought it might be an issue with a recent change to SSL so have updated all links to HTTPS.  I have also cleared all the caches and tried deactivating the plugin to see if that made a difference, but it hasn't.

Within the Avada theme I have removed and readded the logos in case there was a bug, but that hasn't made a different.  I have also removed and readded the custom CSS in case there was an issue picking it up correctly.

I have run [https://validator.w3.org][7] checks and says an error with retina version of logos, but this is not used.

The only other error it logs is:

```
Error: Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
From line 347, column 61; to line 347, column 99   

    gncenter"><style type="text/css" scoped="scoped">.fusio

Contexts in which element style may be used:
Where metadata content is expected.
In a noscript element that is a child of a head element.
In the body, where flow content is expected.
Content model for element div:
If the element is a child of a dl element: one or more dt elements followed by one or more dd elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.
If the element is not a child of a dl element: Flow content.
```

Please advise what else I should try to try to get the website dislaying properly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solve - disabling WP Fastest Cache resolved the issue.